# variable is not passing through php page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In below code **dataString** is not accessible in comment.php page. I have used `$_POST['name']` to get variable name.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click( function() {
var dataString='name=vinay';
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "comment.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
//.after(html); 
alert(html);
}
});
 clearInput();
});

$("#commentForm").submit( function() {
  return false; 
});

function clearInput() {
    $("#commentForm :input").each( function() {
   $(this).val('');
   $("#submit").val('Post');
});
}
});
```

Is anything wrong with this code? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try giving 'name:vinay'

Comment: what does print_r($_POST) give you on comment.php?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var dataString='{name : "vinay"}';
```

instead of

```
var dataString='name=vinay';
```

Comment: what is output of print_r($_POST); on  comment.php?

Comment: hey thanks for help me. I replaced the files to another directory then codes are working but in my project directory its not working what would be the problem. any idea

Answer (score 0):

data = {};

```
data.string = 'your name';
```

then change
below url

( data : data )

Also check ur post whether name arrives or not

Comment: i have tried all these stuff but i don't know why  variables are not accessible on my php page..

Comment: echo that post name,did u get ur name

Comment: then how it pases through ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try putting you ajax function in the submit of the form

```
$("#commentForm").submit( function() {

//ajax code here 

return false; 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this format

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { 
        name: "John", 
        location: "Boston"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is ok, just remove return false; from your code from where you are trying to submiting the form.

```
$("#commentForm").submit( function() {
  return false; //remove this
});
```